# I am getting error for the login route TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, cs50

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)


        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                          username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
    return apology("TODO")
```

[image]
[image]

when i run the above code for pset9 finance it is giving this error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

As i understand the problem is in line 192:

```
session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
```

Can anybody put forward his/her opinion?

Comment: Your `rows[0]` is a int obj?

Comment: so what could be the solution?

Comment: you can debug the code, look over the rows data.

Comment: debug50 is not going through

Comment: when i changed that to session["user_id"] = rows["username"]["id"] error is "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: print the `rows`

Comment: complete code is here but login was lready implemented https://pastebin.com/NZWXrnsk

Comment: My env can't run the code, what the `rows` looks like?

Comment: results = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :password)", username = username, password = hashed)

Comment: And then session["user_id"] = results['id']

Answer (score 0):

From some of the comments, the error is coming from register after this line executes:

```
results = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :password)", username = username, password = hashed)
```

From the [Hints](https://docs.cs50.net/2019/x/psets/8/finance/finance.html#hints) section of the spec:

> If `str` is an `INSERT`, and the table into which data was inserted
>   contains an autoincrementing `PRIMARY KEY`, then `execute` returns the
>   value of the newly inserted row’s primary key.

Therefore this line `session["user_id"] = results[0]['id']` gives an error because `results` is an integer.

----ORIGINAL ANSWER -----

Actually, the problem is in `index`. One can expect `login` from the distro code to work. `login` is redirected to `"/"` (index function).

When you run the code locally, it will produce the same error when logging in a registered user. The traceback in the flask terminal should direct your attention to:

`user = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id", id = session["user_id"][0]["cash"])`

Notice, it is trying to set id to `session["user_id"][0]["cash"]`. `session["user_id"]` is an int. Double check the syntax.

Comment: Hey thanks for time:
Traceback from flask terminal:
File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 291, in register
    session["user_id"] = results[0]['id']
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Flask has a [debug mode](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#debug-mode). You could internet search "debugging flask with pdb", there's lots of results. IME using the feedback in the flask terminal (and perhaps adding printf's to appear in the log) always did the trick for me.

Comment: added new info to the answer, based on collection of comments

Comment: Then there is another error,     user = round(user, 2)
TypeError: type list doesn't define __round__ method